# How I can keep aggregate initialization while also adding custom constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, aggregate-initialization

If I don't define a constructor in a struct, I can initialize it by just picking a certain value like this:

```
struct Foo {
    int x, y;
};

Foo foo = {.y = 1};
```

But if I add new default constructor then I lose this feature:

```
struct Bar {
    int x, y;
    Bar(int value) : x(value), y(value) {}
};

Bar bar1 = 1;
Bar bar2 = {.y = 2}; // error: a designator cannot be used with a non-aggregate type "Bar"
```

Is it possible to have both ways?

I tried adding the default constructor `Bar () {}` but it seems to not work either.

Comment: Have you tried `= default` instead of `{} `

Comment: Once you add a non-default constructor, your structure is no longer an [*aggregate*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) (like a plain old C-like structure, or an array). You can have one or the other, but not both.

Comment: @Sebastian it seems like this doesn't work either `Bar() = default;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh I see, thank you. The closest I got was like this `Bar(Vec2 value) : x(value.x), y(value.y){};` but then I have to use double parens like this `Bar bar2 = {{.y = 2}}`

Comment: @Sebastian He want's aggregate initialization and not a default constructor. The question is misleading and should be edited. I don't believe there is a way to reinstate the aggregate constructor once you have a constructor. Could be a nice C++ extension though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to what ellipticaldoor wrote:

```
struct FooBase {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
};

struct Foo : FooBase {
    Foo(int x_) : FooBase{.x = x_} { }
    Foo(FooBase &&t) : FooBase{t} {}
};

Foo foo = {{.y = 1}};
Foo foo2{1};
```

Answer (score 34):

You can't have your cake and eat it too. If the object has a constructor it is no longer an aggregate, and only aggregates can be initialized with designated initializers. You can't use constructors for arbitrary initialization logic with aggregates.

Are we toasted though? No, because there's the "named constructor" idiom. It's essentially just a static member function that returns an initialized object, and able to perform some logic. The idiom is compatible with aggregate initialization.

```
struct Foo {
    int x, y;
    static Foo filled_with(int value) {
        return {.x = value, .y = value};
    }
};

Foo foo = {.y = 1}; // Still an aggregate.
Foo foo2 = Foo::filled_with(2); // Custom logic
```

There's not even any copying or moving with this approach, because C++17 removed the possibility for those. `foo2` is initialized **directly** with whatever the static member does.

Answer (score 3):

So far this is the closest thing I can find:

```
struct Vec2 {
    int x, y;
};

struct Bar {
    int x, y;
    Bar(int value) : x(value), y(value) {}
    Bar(Vec2 value) : x(value.x), y(value.y){};
};

Bar bar1 = 1;
Bar bar2 = {{.y = 2}};
```

But you need to use double params

Comment: This is the same solution that I came up with.  I like StoryTeller's solution better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a data member initializer instead so the type remains an aggregate:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    int x = 0, y = x;
};

Foo foo1 = {.y = 6};  // Foo{0, 6}
Foo foo2{7};          // Foo{7, 7}
```

(Though it can't be implicitly constructed from `int`)

Comment: oh, this interesting, but the issue will be this though

`Foo foo1 = {.x = 6}; // Foo{6, 6}` I will like in this case for `y` to stay at zero

Comment: @ellipticaldoor There would be no difference between `{.x = 6}` and `{6}` if that is aggregate initialization of `Foo`, so you would have to do something like the other answers